# More flexible citation formats

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I love to use citations in my r bookdown projects.

The format is not very flexible, I can use @citeID to get "Author(Year)" or [@citeID] to get "(Author Year)".

Sometimes I only need "(Year)" or "Year" or I may only need "Author Year" with no parentheses at all.

Finally I need to add a page reference to the citation like "Author (Year:Pages)"

Can anybody give me a hint, where the relevant code sits in the source so that I can start adding some cite-formats as described above?

Answer (score 6):

There are many citation modifications offered by Markdown, many of which you can find in the [Pandoc Users Guide](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations). With them you can hide the author, make page references, etc.:

- `@Einstein1905` -- Einstein et al. (1905)
- `[@Einstein1905]` -- (Einstein et al., 1905)
- `[see @Einstein1905, pp. 23-42]` -- (see Einstein et al., 1905, pp. 23-42)
- `Einstein was right [-@Einstein1905]` -- Einstein was right (1905)

Details like [switching off paranthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style) or other punctuation related issues can be regulated in detail by [designing your own biblatex style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-or-personalize-bst-files). 
These [style files can be tested here](https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/pandoc-csl-testing) and can be [referenced during markdown conversion](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-rendering) using commands like `--biblatex`.